# Two div in same line using css

Tags: css, html, styles

I want to make two div tags in same line. I tried using css property such as display: inline.But it doesn't work. I want the two dropdown boxes to be displayed in same line. Here's the code

```
<div id="block1">
            <label>Select State</label>
            <div class="styled-select green rounded" style="width: 10%; margin-bottom: 2vw;">
                <select class="dropdown-toggle" ng-model="selectedState"
                        ng-options="item for item in states | orderBy:'toString()'"
                        ng-change="stateChanged(selectedState)">
                    <option>State</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="block2" ng-show="showSecondDropDown">
            <label>Select County</label>
            <div class="styled-select green rounded" style="width: 10%">
                <select ng-model="selectedCounty"
                        ng-options="arr.countyName for arr in countyList | orderBy:'countyName' track by arr.countyId "
                        ng-change="tp(selectedCounty)">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the css

```
.styled-select {
    background:
            url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
    height: 29px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
}

.rounded {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.green   { background-color: #779126; }

.styled-select select {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 29px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 268px;
}
#block1, #block2{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Wrap them both together in a single `div` tag and apply the css to them to make them display together `display: inline; float: left` (you can float them to whatever you side you want, I just chose left as an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **flex** by simply wrapping them into a `container` and apply `display:flex` like this (i also removed some useless inline styles) :

```css
.styled-select {
  background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
  height: 29px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 240px;
}

.rounded {
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.green {
  background-color: #779126;
}

.styled-select select {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 29px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 268px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

#block1,
#block2 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div id="block1">
    <label>Select State</label>
    <div class="styled-select green rounded" style=" margin-bottom: 2vw;">
      <select class="dropdown-toggle" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="item for item in states | orderBy:'toString()'" ng-change="stateChanged(selectedState)">
                    <option>State</option>
                </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="block2" ng-show="showSecondDropDown">
    <label>Select County</label>
    <div class="styled-select green rounded">
      <select ng-model="selectedCounty" ng-options="arr.countyName for arr in countyList | orderBy:'countyName' track by arr.countyId " ng-change="tp(selectedCounty)">
                </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or simply use `inline-block` without adding a new div :

```css
.styled-select {
  background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
  height: 29px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 240px;
}

.rounded {
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.green {
  background-color: #779126;
}

.styled-select select {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 29px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 268px;
}


#block1,
#block2 {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
    <label>Select State</label>
    <div class="styled-select green rounded" style=" margin-bottom: 2vw;">
      <select class="dropdown-toggle" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="item for item in states | orderBy:'toString()'" ng-change="stateChanged(selectedState)">
                    <option>State</option>
                </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="block2" ng-show="showSecondDropDown">
    <label>Select County</label>
    <div class="styled-select green rounded">
      <select ng-model="selectedCounty" ng-options="arr.countyName for arr in countyList | orderBy:'countyName' track by arr.countyId " ng-change="tp(selectedCounty)">
                </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is working but it is changing the display of the dropdown box. The width becomes too small

Comment: @chan remove the width, it's useless, i remove it in my code ;)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
float: left;
```

in CSS and they will align next to each other. Like so:

```
#block1, #block2{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```